# Populate text message (outgoing ph# & message) when QR code Scanned in iphone, android & blackberry

Tags: android, iphone, ios, blackberry, sms

When a user scans a QR code, can you open up their outgoing SMS screen and pre-populate both the phone# and the text message body so all they have to do is touch "SEND" to send the SMS?

I'm asking about this solution for iPhones, Androids and Blackberries.

Comment: Quite a vague question, given that you would use completely different approaches on each platform.

Comment: iphone seems to be the most tricky - sorry for the vagueness. Does this vary not only by platform but by device, carrier, or operating system version as well?

Comment: At least for Android, it should be a one-size-fits-all approach. Others, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done on android by launching an intent with the action set to Intent.ACTIONS_SEND.